# How send id category in link React?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have page where I display all categories with this code

```
{categories.map((category, index) => {
            return(
              <tr key={index}>
                <th scope="row">{index}</th>
                <td>{category.name}</td>
                <td>50</td>
                <td><Link to={{pathname: `/categories/edit/`}}>Edit</Link></td>
                <td><Button variant={'danger'} onClick={deleteCategoryHandler} data-id={category._id}>Delete</Button></td>
              </tr>
            )
          })}
```

But when I create Component edit Category, and there I Need send  with id. which will be better ID and name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to do this:

```
categories.map((category, index) => {
  const location = {
    pathname: `/categories/edit/`,
    state: {
      category,
    },
  };
  return (
    <tr key={index}>
      <th scope="row">{index}</th>
      <td>{category.name}</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>
        <Link
          to={location}
        >
          Edit
        </Link>
      </td>
      <td>
        <Button
          variant={"danger"}
          onClick={deleteCategoryHandler}
          data-id={category._id}
        >
          Delete
        </Button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  );
});
```

and in the destination `component` just use something like this to get `location` object and then its `state` property:

```
const location = useLocation();

const category = location?.state?.category;
```

Comment: if i understood correctly i need import useLocation from react-routed-dom in componen?

Comment: Yes, `import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'`

Comment: Thanks , it works. I have probleme where import useLocation, but i fixed .It was necessary to update react-router-dom to 5.2

Answer (score 1):

If you need to send a category `id`, then an incredibly easy way is to send it as part of the path URL.

Create a route in your `Router` that handles `path="/categories/edit/:id"`. Then construct the appropriate path for the link when mapping.

```
{categories.map((category, index) => {
  return(
    <tr key={index}>
      <th scope="row">{index}</th>
      <td>{category.name}</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>
        <Link to={{pathname: `/categories/edit/${category.id}`}}>
          Edit
        </Link>
      </td>
      <td>
        <Button
          variant={'danger'}
          onClick={deleteCategoryHandler}
          data-id={category._id}
        >
          Delete
        </Button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  )
})}
```

On the receiving route's component the `id` parameter can be accessed via [match](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/match) object using the [useParams](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams) react hook from `react-router-dom`.

```
const { id } = useParams();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add category id variable in your link.

```
{categories.map((category, index) => {
            return(
              <tr key={index}>
                <th scope="row">{index}</th>
                <td>{category.name}</td>
                <td>50</td>
                <td><Link to={{pathname: `/categories/edit/ID/${category._id}`}}>Edit</Link></td>
                <td><Button variant={'danger'} onClick={deleteCategoryHandler} data-id={category._id}>Delete</Button></td>
              </tr>
            )
          })}
```

In your hook Component use useParam() to get category id

```
import {useParams} from "react-router-dom";
const YourComponent = (props) => {
let  { ID } = useParams();
...
}
```